# Custom block in magento

Tags: magento

I have added this block in checkout.xml:

```
<block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
```

Then, I have shown this in cart.phtml:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping');
```

Then, I have made a page as shipping.phtml file in cart folder. This is working on my local PC, but when I follow this path on the server no block is showing. There is one difference between the two environments: on local I am doing all this step in the base folder, but on the server there is a customized theme folder in the default folder.

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check design's configuration on server, is this theme really loaded.

Comment: actually shipping block is showing previously but whnen i made the changes it stop showing. although i have made all the changes again. all are showing but shipping block is not showing

Comment: check, may be there is error in you block or template and it just stop to output

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you added the XML correctly (without any typos). A typo in the XML would probably cause Magento to load the default checkout.xml instead of your custom one, losing your block changes.